# Can I add custom side-effects to a stub in Rails Mocha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, stub

My team uses the Mocha gem for stubbing in Rails.  I understand how to stub a method with `stubs` such that it does nothing, or returns a specific value, but is there a way to stub it such that it runs a certain line of code when called?

I'm looking for something like this:

`object.stubs(:method).runs(p 'Hello world!')`

Does this exist?  I'm open to using additional gems, or implementing whatever methodology people come up with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that `.with()` takes a block, so you can use logic to validate the arguments to a method. Here's its source with comment:

```
#   object = mock()
#   object.expects(:expected_method).with() { |value| value % 4 == 0 }
#   object.expected_method(17)
#   # => verify fails
def with(*expected_parameters, &matching_block)
  @parameters_matcher = ParametersMatcher.new(expected_parameters, &matching_block)
  self
end
```

Mocha probably won't mind if you call `side_effect(); true` in there instead of validate a parameter.

Comment: Awesome.  `object.expects(:method).with { p 'Hello world!' }` totally worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @mrmicrowaveoven make sure to accept the answer if it solved your issue (look for a checkmark belove the answer's score).